# PL/SQL ONLY using a cursor to retrieve data from 2 tables into a new table

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

Hi I need to create a new table to store the data of two tables. Then I would need to create a stored procedure to transfer the data from the two tables into the new one.   I had no problem transferring the data from the first table to the new table, the problem arises when i transfer the data from the second table to the new table. Because instead of being inserted in the row that matches its pubid, it is being inserted into a new row instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close, I'd say.

In the second loop, you shouldn't `INSERT`, but **`UPDATE`** existing row.

Cursor you declared:

```
CURSOR cur_proceedings IS
SELECT pubid, year FROM proceedings;
```

You've used it here:

```
OPEN cur_proceedings;
LOOP
    FETCH cur_proceedings INTO v_proceedings;
    EXIT WHEN cur_proceedings%NOTFOUND;

    -- Instead of INSERT:
    -- INSERT INTO publication_master(proceeding_year)
    -- VALUES(v_proceedings.year);

    -- use UPDATE:
    update publication_master m set
      m.proceeding_year = v_proceedings.year
      where m.pubid = v_proceedings.pubid;
    
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur_proceedings;
```

Comment: Hey, when i removed the insert statement in the second loop and put in your suggestion and executed it in the SQL command line. It produced an error and said "PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CUR_PROCEEDINGS"."PUBID": invalid identifier" as well as "PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'CUR_PROCEEDINGS' reference is         out of scope". How would i proceed from here on

Comment: You shouldn't have got it. I edited the answer and put some more code; have a look.

Comment: Yes i did the exact same thing. But im not sure why its still producing the same error.

Comment: Ah! Apologies, should have been `v_proceedings` (i.e. the cursor variable), not `cur_proceedings`. Fixed.